# System.getProperty("java.version") vs Class.forName fallback

Tags: java

There are different approaches to get Java version. The one is to look in system properties, but there is one with looking at available classes.

```
try {                                             
// 1.0                                           
version = 10;                                    

Class.forName("java.lang.Void");                 
// 1.1                                           
version++;                                       

Class.forName("java.lang.ThreadLocal");          
// 1.2                                           
version++;                                       

Class.forName("java.lang.StrictMath");           
// 1.3                                           
version++;                                       

Class.forName("java.lang.CharSequence");         
//1.4                                            
version++;                                       

Class.forName("java.net.Proxy");                 
// 1.5                                           
version++;                                       

Class.forName("java.net.CookieStore");           
// 1.6                                           
version++;                                       

Class.forName("java.nio.file.FileSystem");       
// 1.7                                           
version++;                                       

Class.forName("java.lang.reflect.Executable");   
// 1.8                                           
version++;                                       
} catch (Throwable t) {                           
}
```

I am interested in efficiency of one over another. Can anyone comment?

Answer (score 1):

> I am interested in efficiency of one over another. Can anyone comment?

of course straight forward reading from properties is faster and straight forward & self maintained

Comment: System.getProperty does permission check, however Class.forName is straight native method invocation. Can you prove with explanation of mechanics for both methods?

Comment: Classpath scanning & loading and exception based desicion is more expensive than checking permission I think, You can benchmark it

Answer (score 0):

In practice, your second method is not "efficient" at all. if you find the version from properties, use that.